# Is ID@Xbox restricted to established studios?

Tags: xbox

I read through the [ID@Xbox site](http://www.xbox.com/en-us/Developers/id) but don't totally understand the program. I am a software developer who has made a few Flash games on my own and would like to try to port or recreate one of them for Xbox One.

Is this program only for established game studios?

Comment: Something about that title seems... wrong. I know you did not mean that sardonically, but it sort of sounds that way when I read it ;) Perhaps "Is ID@Xbox open to the public?" would be a better use of language? That said, the program is subject to a review board -- you have to submit an application. There is a separate program Microsoft is working on for individuals to use their ***own*** Xbox One to develop games without the need for a dedicated dev kit. Kind of like Xbox Indy games, only not as restrictive.

Comment: I see. So for the time being I am out of luck

Comment: Others have adequately addressed questions about the scope of ID@Xbox program here, but I wanted to note that Flash is not a supported technology for Xbox One. Currently you can use C++ with a "DirectX App" model very similar to Windows Store app development, you can use JavaScript/HMLT5, or for C# you can use [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/). You can get a long, long way down the road of development on a Windows Store app or a DirectX 11 Win32 desktop app before worrying about needing an Xbox One dev kit.

Comment: For C++ development, these are all public resources that apply to Xbox One development: [Dual-use Coding Techniques for Games](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games.aspx), [x64 native](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/16/windows-x64.aspx), [Direct3D 11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/07/11/getting-started-with-direct3d-11.aspx), [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx), and [no D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is specifically designed for independent developers of any size, *not* established studios. Established studios have the more traditional Xbox developer program open to them.

I think the page you linked makes it very clear:

> ID@Xbox is shorthand for the Independent Developers Publishing Program
>   for Xbox One, a new program **enabling independent game developers of**
>   **all sizes** to produce and self-publish games digitally on Xbox One.

You can [apply to the program](https://xidbox.azurewebsites.net/en-US/Apply/Games) right now. You don't need existing hardware. There is no application fee for the program and, if accepted, you get access to two development kits.

Whether or not you *will* be accepted is another matter, and not something we can answer. In the early days of the program, bias will likely be shown to more established developers (in the sense that they already have games that show well to bring to the system), but that does not preclude your acceptance.

Comment: You misinterpreted my comment, I never said that you need your own hardware for the ID@Xbox program. They will give you up to 2 free devkits if your application qualifies you. I was referring to Microsoft's plans to expand later such that individuals who do not have the adequate background and track record of shipped titles to their name and who would not qualify for ID@Xbox can use their retail console as a devkit. That is something entirely separate, more akin to Xbox Live Indy Games as they exist in the 360 universe. And I never once mentioned anything about an application ***fee***.

Comment: Yeah I read on the site that indie developers of all sizes will be able to produce so I went to apply but it asks me all about the titles my studio has produced etc.. which makes me think my fairly blank application has no chance of being accepted. My poorly worded question was meant to be more around their review board and if someone like me has any real chance of being accepted.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I didn't mean to imply you said anything about a fee, but I did misread your comment about the hardware, sorry. ZWand19, I know a few people who have been accepted with a relatively limited portfolio of games, but nobody can really say anything about your chances. It's not a lottery (primarily), and it's not going to cost you anything but some time to *try*.

Comment: I think the better question of @ZWand19 perhaps "Does ID@Xbox allow Independent Individuals without any **Legally registered business name with suffix**". I myself wanted to develop an Xbox One Game in Unity, however, it requires me to sign-up for this to test games on actual Xbox One device through their GDKs. Unfortunately, required fields are the informations about legally registered business, etc.